# foursquare event api cant get the global intent to work

Tags: foursquare

Hi I cant get the global intent to work for me

I am trying to use the intent=global, which says that the other parameters are then ignored:

"global Finds the most globally relevant venues for the search, independent of location. Ignores all other parameters other than query and limit."

So I thought, Ok I'll add a near to satisfy the api and the global intent will then ignore it. however it doesn't ignore my near. Here's the parameters I am trying:

v=20130618&limit=1&intent=global&query='beirut%20hilton' which fails with "Must provide parameters (ll and radius) or (sw and ne) or (near and radius)"

v=20130618&limit=1&near='harpenden'&intent=global&query='beirut%20hilton'

and of course this finds what I was really after:

v=20130618&limit=1&near='harpenden'&intent=global&query='beirut%20hilton'

when I add a near of somewhere ion the UK, its returning UK based results - which is not the intent!

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for venues in a specific region, do not provide `intent=global`. `intent=global` and `near=` are not compatible.